Floating point error on connection with monetdbe, from lazarus, but not from Delphi
L.S,  I am writing a series of drivers for Lazarus and Delphi, so that MonetDB/e can be used there as well, but i encounter connection problem with Lazarus. I have created an import unit for monetdbe.dll, but when i call the function monetdbe_open  i get a "Floating point division by zero" in Lazarus, while when i call the same function in Delphi it succeeds.
Q: What can cause this on the monetdbe side ?   What does it need on the zero ?
Source :
https://github.com/rudolfterhaar/MonetDBE_Pascal_driver/blob/main/monetdbe.pas
The original c header :
https://www.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB/file/tip/tools/monetdbe/monetdbe.h
Setup : Windows 11, Delphi 12.2, Lazarus 3.6 (FPC 3.2.2)   (everything incl dll 64bits)

And you're sure everybody reading this can reconstruct your issue? F.e. "a wrapper around monetdbe.h" will always come out as it did for you? In other words: provide a [MRE]. Also it's written MonetDB/e.

I see, i'll edit the question, and refrase wrapper. In any case what i meant to say is that to use a dll in pascal you have to create an import unit, where the functions of the dll are imported for use in pascal code.

I'm surprised Delphi is able to see only from the exports of a DLL which convention must be used and which parameters are in and/or out. Hence posted code would be more precise, whereas every reader may use a different Delphi/FPC version.

I used the monetdbe.h header file to make an import unit.   The code is here https://github.com/rudolfterhaar/MonetDBE_Pascal_driver/blob/main/monetdbe.pas

Have you taken care of the portions that are noted with TODO?

It is not a complete driver,far from that , you are correct. But first things first. The import unit is complete, and if the connection it selfs works within Lazarus then i can get this thing completed.

Are both Delphi and Lazarus the same OS and architecture? E.g. both 32-bit or both 64-bit? If so, which one?  FPU/CPU exceptions are architecture specific, and some handling and defaults might be OS specific.

Everything is 64 bits, FPC, Delphi and the dll
